# How can i manage total price in checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

This is the situation:

I charge my clients with 5€ for shipping just if his total ammount is under 60€.

I got checkout-addons plugin installed

- I got an add on that charges 15€ for an additional service
- The additional 15€ are    charged after the cart page (checkout)
- The additional 15€ make the total amount over 60€ but the 5€ shipment is allready added

Then im charging 5€ more than i should.

So my questions are:

- Can i modify this only using wysiwyg tool? (guess not)
- Is there a pluging that can solve this for me (i was thinking in one-page-checkout)
- Is there a solution via php actions, like add a new behaivour to an action that condition the 5€ shipment costs?

Thanks in advance.